# How do i keep my current page menu highlighted on pagination?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, pagination

I have a navigation menu in a page that highlights the current menu you’re on based on the URL by adding a class.

My problem is that my page is paginated, so sometimes the user will end up at:

`http://example.com:4001/wordpress/calientes/page/2/` ,
/page/3/ , /page/4/ and so on...

**what’s the best way to keep my menu highlighted while the user is browsing the pages?**

This is my menu:

```
<div class="innerhead">

<ul>

<li> <a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/calientes/">Calientes </a> </li>
<li><a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/tendencias/">Tendencias</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

This is the Script that i use to highlight the current page menu:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href; 

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $(".innerhead a").each(function() {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be:

```
<div class="innerhead">
  <ul>
    <li id="calientes"> <a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/calientes/">Calientes </a> </li>
    <li id="tendencias"> <a href="http://example.com:4001/wordpress/tendencias/">Tendencias</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In your script:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
$('#'+url[4]).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Are you doing this?
<script> $(document).ready (function (){var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
$('#'+url[4]).addClass("active");}); </script>

Comment: if you are not using $(document).ready() be sure that you are including the script code at the end of the html file

Comment: This script does highlight my menu : <script>
$(function(){
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href; 

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $(".innerhead a").each(function() {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script> but when i use the pagination my Active class stop working...

Comment: The problem is in the index. It is not 4. Use 2. I can not try with your url. To be sure add to your script console.log(window.location.pathname.split('/')); and it will let you find the correct index

Comment: Excelent my friend! It works like a charm!! i change it to '2' and it did work! Thank you so much!